# How can I JIT compile code to run across OSes and for bare metal?

Tags: embedded, llvm, code-generation, jit, webassembly

I'm looking to do some realtime data processing within a cross-platform user-facing application, and I need some kind of just-in-time or just-ahead-of-time compilation of dynamically generated code to get the performance I need. I want to use the same library to generate code for a bare-metal microcontroller, but the microcontroller does not need to JIT anything. What's the best solution for embeddable dynamic code execution?

- I've looked at embedding Clang+LLVM and compiling generated C code on the fly, but couldn't get Clang to compile C from memory.
- WebAssembly via [wasmer](https://wasmer.io/) would be easier to work with than LLVM, but I believe it needs system libraries and executable memory.
- I'm embedding this in C++, but the embedded compiler can be written in any language with a C API.
- Performance is important. I want to do realtime processing without taking more than ~10% CPU time on desktop, and obviously not overloading my microcontroller.
- I'm okay choosing a microcontroller that can run embedded Linux if necessary, provided it can boot nearly instantly.

Comment: If it is a microcontroller it doesnt run linux.  not fully/really.

Comment: I think you are confusing what clang/llvm started out to do and what it really can do.

Comment: There are some mature Lisp-2 implementations which dynamically compile to target assembler. Maybe that would meet your requirements.

Comment: Dynamically generating code to compile in realtime, is slower than not perfectly optimized code that was pre-compiled or if-then-elsing your way through a set of pre-compiled, optimized, algorithms.  Unless you are reusing that dynamically generated code a lot, one generation a very large number of uses of that one generation which makes it not dynamic.

Comment: I need to generate a function once and run it in a tight loop thousands-millions of times. Slowish compilation time is acceptable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think generating and running LLVM IR using the C++ API will be the best solution, unless another option is presented. Though the code generation might be low-level, it supports all relevant platforms, can cross compile, and has exceptional performance.